Нужна ли запятая или тире, при отрицании с утверждением
Техас? Невада? Нет# Татарстан!
Что нужно ставить вместо #?

Поставил бы многоточие. А вот восклицание убал бы. Итог такой:
Техас, Невада? Не-ет... Татарстан.
